# R - set list element name from the element itself

Tags: r, list

I have the following list:

```
list <- list("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to set their names like so:

```
names(list) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

However, when you have a very long list with thousands of entries, that's not so easy to do.

What is the way to take the text from the list element itself and then assign it as the name of this element?

I would like to avoid the usage of for loops and would prefer a tidyverse solution.

```
list %>%
```

?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and never use a name like `list` for a variable. While it still works, it is dangerous and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set_names()` function.

```
mylist <- set_names(list("a", "b", "c"))
```

By default, if the `nm` argument is not provided, the names are taken from the argument itself.

Or, you can do

```
mylist %>% set_names()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dplyr::lst` which returns a named list

```
list1 <- dplyr::lst("a", "b", "c")
list1

#$`"a"`
#[1] "a"

#$`"b"`
#[1] "b"

#$`"c"`
#[1] "c"
```

However, the names of the list are with quotes, if you want to remove them you may add an additional statement to clean that up.

```
names(list1)
#[1] "\"a\"" "\"b\"" "\"c\""

names(list1) <- gsub('"', '', names(list1))
names(list1)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```